# Horde complains for conf.php

Tags: configuration, horde

I have a minimal Debian 7 box and install Horde from this instructions: https://wiki.debian.org/Horde.

Request on `http://localhost/horde` gives

```
A fatal error has occurred
This system is currently deactivated.
Details have been logged for the administrator.
```

When going to `http://localhost/horde/test.php` the page complains for

```
Required Configuration Files
    config/conf.php: No
    You need to login to Horde as an administrator and create the configuration file.
```

In /srv/www/horde/horde/config I have:

```
$ cp conf.php.dist conf.php
$ ll conf.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   3457 Jan  9 11:12 conf.php
```

Apache2 runs with default site with sym link in `/var/www/horde -> /srv/www/horde`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe Horde actually wants you to go to http://localhost/horde/conf.php ?

Answer (score -1):

See my similar trouble in:
https://superuser.com/questions/1056045/horde-configuration/1056052#1056052
Looks that you have not copied/created *conf.php*. Best way is to copy it from config/conf.php.dist -> conf.php